# Using RSpec, are constants within describes a big no-no?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I just spent ages trying to figure out why my specs were passing in isolation, but when running the controller and lib tests together, some specs were mysteriously failing.  The culprit was this:

In one spec:

```
describe SomeThing do
  CONSTANT_VALUE = "a value"

  # ... examples etc ...
end
```

And in another:

```
describe AnotherThing do
  CONSTANT_VALUE = "a different value"

  # ... the rest is history
end
```

The values I'd assigned to these constants was leaking between my specs and causing unexpected behaviour.  Am I supposed to use a `let` block for defining constants etc?  Or something else?

Comment: I think you should use a let in your tests, since describe doen't have it's own variable scoping like a class, module, method, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `let` is the answer here.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of those weird gotchas that might trip a few people up :)  I wonder if the scoping thing is a feature, or a limitation.

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can actually scope the constants to the describe block itself just by declaring them as `self::CONSTANT = 'value'`.  You can still access them without the `self` prefix.  Using `let`, you can use UPPERCASE names, so it doesn't read as clearly IMHO :)